# AUCTeX preview renders tikzpicture wrong

Tags: tikz-pgf, emacs, auctex

I have the following latex document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (o) at (0, 0);

\draw[thick, ->] (o) -- (3, 5.2) coordinate (b) node[left=2mm] {$b$};
\draw[thick, ->] (o) -- (7, 2) coordinate (a) node[right=1mm] {$a$};

\coordinate (p) at ($(0,0)!(b)!(a)$);
\draw[dashed] (p) -- (b);
\draw[thick, ->] (o) -- (p) node[below] {$p$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Running AUCTeX's `preview-at-point` in Emacs generates the following image:

[image: generated picture with AUCTeX preview]

The dashed line and the vector `p` are drawn incorrectly. Running `lualatex example.tex` the following pdf is created:

[image: generated picture with lualatex]

How can I generate a correct preview picture with AUCTeX preview?

Also: how can the font color be set to white for TikZ pictures?

Versions:

- Emacs: 29.2
- AUCTeX: 14.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [preview](https://ctan.org/pkg/preview) package has an issue with TikZ calc syntax.

The TikZ picture is rendered correctly when I add this to the header:

```latex
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\catcode`$=3 } % $
```

As mentioned here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2020-05/msg00004.html

Answer (score 3):

`preview` and `tikz` don't play well.  I suggest you source out the `tikzpicture` into an external file, say `standalone-test.tex` and run `pdflatex` on it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (o) at (0, 0);

  \draw[thick, ->] (o) -- (3, 5.2) coordinate (b) node[left=2mm] {$b$};
  \draw[thick, ->] (o) -- (7, 2) coordinate (a) node[right=1mm] {$a$};

  \coordinate (p) at ($(0,0)!(b)!(a)$);
  \draw[dashed] (p) -- (b);
  \draw[thick, ->] (o) -- (p) node[below] {$p$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

and then include it back in your original file like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\includegraphics[page=1]{standalone-test}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Running `preview` on the file above should look like this in Emacs:
[image]